# VirtualBox does not open

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

VirtualBox does not open and I'm confused.

I removed and re-installed VirtualBox but
VirtualBox is still not open.

I enabled Compatibility mode and tried. It had all options but it does not work at all!!

Also when I re-installed VirtualBox I saw this warning:

> Cannot rename this connection. A connection with the name you specified already exists. Specify a different name.

[Warning when I installed VirtualBox and Genymotion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDJn5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Click Start, click Run, type cmd.exe, and then press ENTER.

2.Type set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1, and then press ENTER.

3.Type Start DEVMGMT.MSC, and then press ENTER.

4.Click View, and then click Show Hidden Devices.

5.Expand the Network Adapters tree.

6.Right-click the dimmed network adapter, and then click Uninstall

Comment: i write devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1 and it's the anwser -'devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.-what can i do?please help, thanks

Comment: check this link [link](https://telnet25.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/cannot-rename-this-connection-a-connection-with-the-name-you-specified-already-exist-specify-a-different-name/)

Comment: I do that, also VirtualBox dose'nt open! do you have an other suggest?

Comment: you can use android studio emulator ,why not ? and i will search about this problem

Comment: my processor is amd and androdi studio dosen't support it.

Comment: do you have an other way?i'm need it too mach!

Comment: windows 10 ? or 7 ??

Comment: check this , and if ok please accept my answer [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/windows-10-vagrant-virtualbox-homestead)

Comment: i said my virtualBox dose'nt open and i don't use Vagrant or
Homestead. i use it with genymotion but it dose'nt open i'm  confused!!

Answer (score 0):

Download genymotion setup [here](https://www.genymotion.com)

There are two options:
with virtualbox and without virtual box

download with virtual box and then install it.

It will work for you

Comment: i dowlnloded genymotion with VirtualBox

Comment: so have you installed it properly?